# Smart data processing - what kind of algorithm should i use?

Tags: algorithm

**Background**:

I'm trying to build a smart information system.

These are my 2 objects for the example:

1. **Pub** - each Pub has its own properties like: size, pub type, music type, hot bartenders, etc..
2. **Drinker** - each drinker has its own properties like: favorite music type, favorite drinks, etc..

I want to create a database that will save all drinker's behavior, like adding new row of data each time the drinker went to a specific bar with specific properties.

**Question:**

I want to create an algorithm that will analyze drinker's behavior and will know to rate each Pub according to drinker's properties and behavior..

Is there some kind of known "smart" algorithm that knows how to process this kind of data ?

**Type of solutions i thought about (will glad to get feedback and directions for getting started):**

- Give a weight to each one of drinker's properties and Pub's identical properties
- Calculate the Pub's properties to a grade
- Sort the Pub's according to the grade they received and show it to the drinker

I don't know if i'm on the right direction - but even if i do - i don't really understand how to start..

Comment: stackoverflow must make down voters comment...

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here because you have poorly stated goals, Specifically, "*I want to create an algorithm that will analyze drinker's behavior and will know to rate each Pub according to drinker's properties and behavior...is there an algorithm for this?*", but ***for what purpose?*** There are potentially thousands of different algorithms that you could use, starting with just rate the pubs based on how many people go to each one.  That's a great algorithm, but it may not serve your purpose, but, since you haven't told us what that is, we cannot give any better answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some kind of known "smart" algorithm that knows how to process this kind of data ?

Before you can start working on a solution, you need to define your goals first.

What is the goal of all this ranking activity? Are you trying to find the most frequently visited bar? the most profitable? the one where patrons visits the longest? the one that is most enjoyable? What are you trying to do with the rankings? Are you making recommendations of a bar to visit based on the drinker's properties?

Comment: I want the algorithm recommand the drinker which pub is the pub he will enjoy in most

Comment: @AsafNevo: this looks like a good problem for a machine learning/neural net algorithm. The input would be the drinker's profile, and the output is the "rating" that the drinker gives to the bar. You'll feed the neural net algorithm with learning data abut how they enjoy their visit to the bar; when trying to give recommendation, you'll try to predict what rating they will give to the bar based on the drinker's profile, the system then recommends bars where the neural net predicts is going to be rated highest by the drinker.

Comment: @AsafNevo: You would want to learn about neural network, and experiment with various training algorithms to find out which ones would be the most appropriate for your situation. For example, [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning), [active learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_learning_%28machine_learning%29), etc.

Comment: Thanks for great comment... add it as anaswer so i can except it

Answer (score 1):

You can do a sort of "simulation."

Drinker(1)

- Music - Electronic
- Drinks - Beer
- Age - 21

Bar(1)

- Music - Country
- Drinks - Only alcohol
- Age group - 40-50

Bar(2)

- Music - Electronic and Rock
- Drinks - everything
- Age group - 21-30

The drinker would give bar 2 a higher grade based on the types of stuff he likes and rate bar 1 less.

Recurse through all the people based on the bar.

Give weight to stuff that matters more (service and age are more important then lets say napkin colors) Then average those results up, this should give you a good rating on that particular bar. I would make the weight at a high level. So you can dynamically change what matters.

Comment: Thanks for a simple answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say some combination would be your best bet.  Another good one you should consider is grouping like drinkers together; given that your algorithm runs for a long enough time, it should be able to piece together that drinker A frequents bar B and thus likely enjoys bar B; you can then use the information for drinkers similar to A and recommend bar B for them, or find bars similar to B for user A to visit.  Trying to do a simple matching algorithm to pair users to bars is naive, as tags are nothing more than tags, and need to use information gathered over time to update and improve its ratings.  Of course asking the user to give ratings would dramatically speed up the process, but if you don't want to have to ask then it will take time for the algorithm to pick up accuracy.